# PHP Rest Web API multiple functions in single file

Tags: c#, php, web, asp.net-web-api

I have seen many links on how to make a web-api using PHP, and all of the examples would put each "function" in a different file. I once helped my friend develop an asp.net C# web api where a single file would contain multiple functions.

Can this be done in PHP? i.e can a single PHP file contain multiple functions that a web-api can call? If so can you kindly give me an example of how it is done, or refer me to a link where this is explained?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a framework to build your API, don't reinvent the wheel.

If you must, you need to find a "discriminator", or how you know what kind of request has to end up at which function.

You can do so using the HTTP verb, the URL, HTTP headers and whatnot. Frameworks do this for you, so you only have to write the code you're interested in.

Again, if you must, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

function DoPost()
{
  // ...
}

function DoPut()
{
  // ...
}

function DoGet()
{
  // ...
}

function Main()
{
  switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
  {
    case 'GET':
      return DoGet();
    case 'PUT':
      return DoPut();
    case 'POST':
      return DoPost();
  }
}

Main();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that!
Since I'm new to PHP I don't know what tools are available. What framework would you recommend?
Thanks again.

Comment: @Noel none, as I didn't do APIs in PHP recently and off-site advice is off-topic for SO. Just search the web for "php web api framework" and compare the results.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that (regarding the off-site advice).
Thanks again.